# Error code with discord .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, discord.py

```
 @bot.command(pass_conetext = True)
async def info(ctx,  user: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Super Bot", description = "Thinking" , color = 0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name = "Name", value = user.name, inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "ID", value = user.id , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "Status", value = user.status , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "Highest Role", value = user.top_role , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "Joined", value = user.joined_at , inline = True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = user.avatar_url)
```

every time i run this code it comes back with this error and i have no idea why

```
Ignoring exception in command info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in invoke
    yield from self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 345, in prepare
    yield from self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 304, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = yield from self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Stuart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 212, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument('{0.name} is a required argument that is missing.'.format(param))
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user is a required argument that is missing.
```

can somone please explain why and maybe a solution thanx

Comment: How are you invoking the command?  What are you typing into Discord to get the command to run?

Comment: to run the command is it <info @the user it used to work then it stoped and i have no idea why

Comment: You've misspelled `pass_conetext`, it should be `pass_context`.  That might effect what arguments get passed into the command

Comment: that has solved this thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Whoever ran the command didn't have the `user` argument.

`!info @user` instead of `!info`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to this to deny the error:

```
@bot.command(pass_context= True)
async def info(ctx,  user: discord.Member=None):
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.message.author
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Super Bot", description = "Thinking" , color = 0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name = "Name", value = user.name, inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "ID", value = user.id , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "Status", value = user.status , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "Highest Role", value = user.top_role , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "Joined", value = user.joined_at , inline = True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = user.avatar_url)
```

Basically if the user is nothing it will give the message authors info..